# How to rewrite Ubuntu with Windows 10?

Tags: uninstall

So I've really tried to give ubuntu a chance but I can't seem to get anything done without issues. I've used a Windows 10 computer of my roommates to make a recovery drive and I've gotten so far as to have removed GRUB and installed the BIOS, but when I try to fresh install it says "A required drive partition is missing" How do I fix this? I can boot into Windows 10 recovery but can't do much outside of that.

Comment: But that's outdated and for Windows 7. Windows 10 recovery works differently

Comment: ""A required drive partition is missing" How do I fix this? " Not our problem ;-)  that is a Windows specific error so that should be asked on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried boot-repair while live booting Ubuntu with USB drive? if you haven't yet, you should try it and make following commands:
  `$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`
  `$ sudo apt-get install boot-repair`

after installing, you can run boot-repair via either terminal or application menu

On another hand, you can try to fix GRUB on windows with Easybcd also !

Comment: I think @Dinkleberg- is trying to remove GRUB completely and reinstall Windows, not trying to fix GRUB :)